# "Close window" (Ctrl+q) Shortcut not working on every window

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

In Linux Mint Cinnamon there are a lot of tools that can not be closed using Ctrl+q. For example the "Software Manager"..
Is there a reason for this strange behavior?
Can I somehow make Ctrl+q work on any active window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely up to the individual application what to do what it catches a certain keypress.  You might be able to configure the Window Manager to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> as a "close active window" key, though.

Comment: And where can I configure the Window Manager like that?

Comment: ...which window manager?

Comment: I'm using Mint Cinnamon. Sorry I'm new to it.

Comment: Found it. The shortcut for closing any window in Mint Cinnamon can be found under "System Settings" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Windows"

Comment: Glad I was able to point you in the right direction.